# Curb Gem not working in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl

I'm a ruby user and now trying to convert a couple of expressions in curl php to Ruby. I installed gem "Curb" and typed a below command. But the browser said "cannot load such file -- curl". How can I know that the gem is well installed? or Are my commands wrong?

```
  def  test
    require 'curl' # or require 'curb'
    request_url = 'https://api.iamport.kr/payments/abcdefg'
    c =  Curl::Easy.perform(request_url)
    @body = c.body_str
  end
```

I am willing to start from very beginning by changing a line by line. But I'm stuck at this first line! I'm looking forward to hearing opinions!!

Best

Answer (score 0):

Install both: `curl` and `curb`:

```
gem install curl    
gem install curb
```

Then, this code works fine:

```
def test
    require 'curb'
    request_url = 'https://api.iamport.kr/payments/abcdefg'
    c =  Curl::Easy.perform(request_url)
    @body = c.body_str
    p @body
end

test
```

If you are using this in a Rails app, in your `Gemfile`, add:

```
gem curl  
gem curb
```

and then run:

```
bundle install.
```

Comment: Thanks! But still it says "cannot load such file -- curb" I just installed the gem and curb-0.8.8, and curl-0.0.9 but still it says that. Am I missing something here? By the way this code in the controller to test first ( I usually put in the model or helper! )

Comment: So, you are using it in a Rails app? Did you install `curl` and `curb` gems using bundler? Do one quick test first. Put the above code in a separate ruby file and run it, see if that works. Then, we will know problem is your Rails app specific or not. Let me know.

Comment: Also, try adding: `require 'rubygems'` as well. (If you are not using bundler and don't have a `Gemfile`). If you have a `Gemfile`, then add: `gem curl` and `gem curb` to your Gemfile and then run:  `bundle install`. See if that works.

Comment: make sure you include the gems in `Gemfile`; then `bundle install`.. no need of `require`, the `rails app` does require

Comment: After I put gem in "Gemfile" now I can go to the next step. The error now I have is "uninitialized constant AdminController::Curl" in "c=Curl::Easy.perform(request_url)" part. How can I call the method correctly?

Comment: Try this: `c =  ::Curl::Easy.perform(request_url)` and let me know.

Comment: Hi K M! Still not responding :( . Because it didn't work :( Saying same error like just without ::

Comment: Do you have the repo on github that I can take a look? or can you reproduce the problem in a sample project? Let me know.